# Copyright of graphic designs provided to ex-partner who is not paying

Tags: copyright, legal

As a freelance graphic artist, I designed a logo, flyer, and truck signage for an ex partner´s business.

Partner, as in significant other, not a "business" partner.

I want to know, what right do I have to refuse the use my designs any further.

There was no payment and no contract.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think you should ask your lawyer. I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is a legal question. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you *voluntarily agreed* to work for free yesterday, you can't ask for payment or return of the work next week merely because you are angry.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I am not a laywer.)

If you don't have a contract, then you're SOL. You gave away your intellectual property without any restrictions on its usage.

You did own the copyright until you handed it over to the other person. You deliberately made the artwork to be used as corporate identification, not just a one-off T-shirt or poster, so your original intent was clear. If the other person has been using the artwork for any length of time, and has built up any kind of visual equity, you've lost any claim you might have had.

If you didn't get paid, you're also SOL. Not that you might not deserve monetary compensation, but *at the time* you did not ask for or expect any (underscored by the lack of contract), and if you were in a relationship, the "payment" might have been in affections.

Consider it a lesson learned. Don't do anything without a contract, even for friends/partners/family.

Answer (score 1):

Let it go. This is what happens when you do favours. No contract, no real issue.